In lead sheet does tie also apply to chord?
I have a score written in form of a lead sheet. I have a note spanning over two bars, and the note is tied. This I understand.
But what am I supposed to do with the chord written over -- play it (hit the keys) twice, or once (hit and hold keys)? In other word does tie apply to chord too?


The G is tied, so lasting 6 beats. Fact. The chord written above will be the same chord for both bars, but since it's written for basically guitar and/or piano, it will depend on the strumming pattern used.
In 3 time the most common, simple, rhythm will be 3 strums per bar, and because that part is playing rhythm, there is likely to be 6 strums occurring over those two bars.
So, no, the tie references only the note to which it's attached, not the chord. Likewise, any notes which are syncopated may well not follow the written syncopation. Although that rhythm could, depending on what sounds good at the time.

Ties are not applicable to chord symbols.
A chord stays in place until there's a chord change. If there's a note with a tie to the next bar, there may be a chord change, or not. If there isn't a chord change notated, you keep playing the same chord.
Here you change chord:

 - as you can hear at 0:11.
And here you keep playing the same chord (until you arrive at the N.C. sign that tells you to stop playing any chord):

 - as you can hear at 0:23.
Most often chord changes come at the start of a bar (but not every bar). But it isn't a rule and there may be several chord changes in one bar.

"A chord stays in place until there's a chord change.". You mean you strike the keys of the chords once, or do you mean that you don't change chord to some other (unwritten) chord? In my question I was referring to hitting the keys once, or twice.

Keys? There was nothing about the question (at the time I was writing the answer) about which instrument you play. Most often people use chord symbols for playing guitar and similar instruments that you strum in a regular rhythm. Well, in the case of a piano, it's... kinda up to you to figure out how you should voice the chord on the keys. In the simplest case when you hit them simultaneously and hold, feel free to hit them again any time you feel like it's a good idea. If you're a beginner, then "every start of a bar" sounds like a reasonable starting point to me.

My bad, sorry :-) I am so focused on practicing, that I forget there are other instruments :-). Yes, I am beginner. Thank you for clarification.

@greenoldman the chord symbols say nothing about how many times to play the chord.  You might play the chord twelve times over these two measures; you might never play the whole chord all at once (for example if you are using an arpeggiated figure, playing something like C-E-G-C-G-E in succession).

Lead sheets don't tell you how to realize the chords. They tell you what the chords are and when they change; your job is to play notes from the current chord in a way that supports the music harmonically and rhythmically.
There's nothing wrong with keeping it simple if that suits your skill level. But you'll still have to use your discretion to fill in gaps like this one. Does it feel like you should strike the chord again? Then do. Lead sheets aren't designed to answer that question.

No, a tie over the melody notes doesn't apply to the playing of the chords.  Chords are more tightly connected to the beats and to the rhythmic pattern of the accompaniment.
If you provide a snapshot of those 2 bars and the surrounding bars of the lead sheet, my answer could have been more specific.

Let's say the tie crosses the bar line, most likely you would play the chords twice.

Let's say the chord changes under the scope of the tie (which sometimes happen), then you definitely need to play the 2nd chord in the middle of the tie.

Etc.



Ok, thank you, I updated the question.

@greenoldman Well, if it is the end of the song, probably you wouldn't play it again.  It really depends on the style of the accompaniment more than the tie of the melody.  But notation wise, nothing prevents you from hitting the chord again.  It also depends on the instrument.  If it is pipe organ, then you wouldn't play it, if it's piano, then you probably don't need to (optional), but if you have been strumming in the guitar, you wouldn't want to stop the strumming, etc.

"Let's say the tie crosses the bar line, most likely you would play the chords twice": most likely you would play the chord anywhere between four and twelve times in the example given here.

First, as others have noticed, if you are wanting to "sustain" a C-chord sound (for example), on piano you'd have to do something, because the resonance won't last two measure in a typical tempo. The choice of the "something certainly depends on the style".
Another point is that, for example, on piano, accompaniments often are based on an easy-vanilla harmonic concept. So, instead of just fiddling around to sustain the "C", you can do a circle-of-fifths riff, and/or a quick blues-pattern, as a "fill". Depends on what everyone else is doing. (Probably do not want to hijack the thing from the singer/soprano. :)
